# How to print the integer equivalent of symbols in c?

Tags: c, printf, ascii

**I am trying to print the integer equivalents of symbols ; : ? . and whitespace but it doesn't work.**

```
printf( "Following symbols ending with a whitespace: - = + / \ ; : ? . [whitespace]\n" );

printf( "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", '-', '=', '+', '/', '\', ';', ':', '?', '.', ' ' );
```

**I have successfully printed the integer equivalents of A-Z, a-z, 0-20, and other symbols. However when I try to compile this line there seems to be a problem with the symbols from semicolon to the right. 
I get the following error from my Command Prompt for VS 2019.**

```
IntegerValueOfChar.c(29): warning C4129: ' ': unrecognized character escape sequence

IntegerValueOfChar.c(31): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant'

IntegerValueOfChar.c(31): warning C4473: 'printf' : not enough arguments passed for format string

IntegerValueOfChar.c(31): note: placeholders and their parameters expect 10 variadic arguments, but 5 were provided

IntegerValueOfChar.c(31): note: the missing variadic argument 6 is required by format string '%d'

IntegerValueOfChar.c(31): error C2137: empty character constant

IntegerValueOfChar.c(31): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

**How can I resolve this? I am using notepad++ together with the Visual Studio Compiler.
Thanks for helping a frustrated noob.**

Comment: In order to give a character literal for the backslash, you have to use **two** backslashes! So, change your `'\'` argument to `'\\'`.  See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the backslash character is used as an escape prefix within character constants and string literals. To represent an actual backspace character as a character constant or within a string literal, it needs to be doubled up:

```
printf( "Following symbols ending with a whitspace: - = + / \\ ; : ? . [whispace]\n" );
printf( "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", '-', '=', '+', '/', '\\', ';', ':', '?', '.', ' ' );
```